# Date.parse() is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to know whether the given string is datetime, so i used the Date.parse() method as below

```
var dateType=!isNaN(Date.parse("2/3/2012")) // return true;
```

but for the string "2000" i am getting dateType as true

```
var dateType=!isNaN(Date.parse("2000")) // return true;
```

i want to return true when the format like "mm/dd/yyyy" is used in string not for "2000", is there any method to to like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about `Date.parse()`... [___This is an alternative___](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587398/2260614)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regular expression to validate.

for mm/dd/yyyy format use the below regex

```
 var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
```

and you could test using

```
date_regex.test("11/09/2011")
```

also there are many other ways to do it. explore them also